# How to get an executable Python path out of an Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, windows-10, anaconda, codexl

I am trying to profile my pyopencl project with CodeXL, and in order to work with .py files. I can't think of anything better than pointing at Python.exe and passing path to script as an argument. What makes things complicated is my use of Anaconda virtual environment to resolve conflicts between modules, because this way it is impossible to simply point CodeXL at a python executable in some virtual environment - as far as I understand, this environment has to be activated first, and CodeXL does not support this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python executable of a conda, virtualenv or venv environment is generally located at

```
$ENVPATH/bin/python
```

EDIT: on Windows should be instead (at least for venv)

```
$ENVPATH\Scripts\python.exe
```

where `$ENVPATH` is the environment path. To get a list of the environments you created along with their paths you can run (from the terminal)

```
conda env list
```

Alternatively, if you are using a Python interpreter and you want to know where its executable is located, you can run

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the location of your python exe using:

```
where python
```

Since you're using Anaconda, you can also try:

```
where anaconda
```

You'll find the python exe in the parent directory of the result.

If this isn't what you need, you can find more info [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly my problem. I am trying to get an "executable path" that will satisfy CodeXL and allow me to profile my OpenCL scripts - and something like `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env_opencl\pythonw.exe C:\Users\user\projects\particle_system\src\main.py` gets rejected by IDE.

Answer (score 1):

1. This should give you a list of all the environments and their respective paths.

```
conda env list
```

2. copy the path of your desired environment and append `/bin` to it and call the python version, can be either python3 or python2
3. In the end, your path should look like for python2 `/<your_env_path>/bin/python` and this for python3 `/<your_env_path>/bin/python3`

Comment: this does not seem to be working]